# Understanding the working of .enter() in D3 Js and Power BI

Tags: d3.js, powerbi

I am following the video tutorial (https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Azure/Building-Power-BI-custom-visuals-that-meet-your-app-needs) to create a bar chart (custom visual) within Power BI.

Code snippet (in the video at 13.40):

```
    let bars = this.barContainer.selectAll('.bar').data(viewModel.dataPoints);

    bars.enter().append('rect').classed('bar', true);

    bars
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d.value))
        .attr('y', d => yScale(d.value))
        .attr('x', d => xScale(d.category));

    bars.exit().remove();
```

The above code is written in update method of `visual.ts` file.

As per my understanding, the `enter()` method will create `rect` elements with class `bar` based on the `viewModel.dataPoints` data.

The problem is I am **not** able to get it to work upon **initial load**, when the visual is loaded, this **works only** when the visual is **resized**. I cannot see any attributes getting applied on the `rect` elements upon load, but its getting applied when a resize is made on the visual.

If I changed the code to:

```
    bars.enter().append('rect').classed('bar', true)
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d.value))
        .attr('y', d => yScale(d.value))
        .attr('x', d => xScale(d.category));

    bars.transition()
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d.value))
        .attr('y', d => yScale(d.value))
        .attr('x', d => xScale(d.category));

    bars.exit().remove();
```

The above code works fine, The attributes are getting applied for both initial load and resize.

*Additional Info (Constructor code)*

```
    let svg = this.svg = d3.select(options.element).append('svg').classed('barChart', true);
    this.barContainer = svg.append('g').classed('barContainer', true);
    this.xAxis = svg.append('g').classed('xAxis', true);
```

Is this the way its supposed to work in the latest version (D3 Js 5.0)? or I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `.merge()` function does the trick.

The solution is:

```
let bars = this.barContainer.selectAll('.bar').data(viewModel.dataPoints);
        const a = bars.enter().append('rect').merge(<any>bars); // merge before attr()
        a.classed('bar', true);
        a 
            .transition().duration(50)
            .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d.value))
            .attr('y', d => yScale(d.value))
            .attr('x', d => xScale(d.category)); // This code now works for initial 
                                                 // load and update.
        bars.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help talk you through merge.  There is a link at the bottom if you would prefer to use the new join method in d3.js v5.

https://www.codementor.io/@milesbryony/d3-js-merge-in-depth-jm1pwhurw

Or for more complex use see Mike Bostock's

https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join